# Skip input to next line, for reading serialized objects

Tags: c++, io, stream

I was de-serializing objects that had an extra newline that needed to be removed before getting the next object.

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_UTIL_H
#define THORSANVIL_UTIL_H

// Removed headers for   getDist() and getRandomContainerIterator()
// We already reviewed those two. 
#include <iostream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Util
    {

// Removed getDist() and getRandomContainerIterator()
// We already reviewed those two.

class IgnoreUntilNewLine
{
    public:
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, IgnoreUntilNewLine& /*data*/)
        {
            stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            return stream;
        }
};

class SkipEmptyLineToEnd
{
    public:
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, SkipEmptyLineToEnd& /*data*/)
        {
            std::string     emptyLine;
            std::getline(stream, emptyLine);
            if (!emptyLine.empty()) {
                stream.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
            }
            return stream;
        }
};

    }
}

#endif
```

Simplified Example for usage:

```
namespace TU = ThorsAnvil::Util;
struct Example1
{
     int    x;
     int    y;
     std::string  line; // Always one line with no "\n"
     void swap(Example1& other) noexcept {/*Stuff*/}

     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Example1 const& data)
     {
         // Note putting a new line here
         // to make the Serialized object more readable.
         // The actual object was a bit more complicated and
         // I really wanted to make it readable.
         return stream << data.x << " " << data.y << "\n"
                       << data.line << "\n";
     }
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Example1& data)
     {
         Example1  tmp;
         if (stream >> tmp.x >> tmp.y)
         {
             stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
             if (std::getline(stream, tmp.line)) {
                 data.swap(tmp);
             }
         }
         return stream;
     }
};
```

I thought the above read was a bit cumbersome and hard to read. Thus the two types above. This means I can re-write the read operation as:

```
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Example1& data)
     {
         TU::IgnoreUntilNewLine ignoreNewLine;
         Example1               tmp;

         if ((stream >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> ignoreNewLine) && std::getline(stream, tmp.line)) {
             data.swap(tmp);
         }
         return stream;
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes `IgnoreUntilNewLine` and `SkipEmptyLineToEnd` can probably be simplified. Classic indicators for that are that it only has one function and no state. However, the key is the following `operator>>` [overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

```
basic_istream& operator>>( basic_istream& (*func)(basic_istream&) );
```

In other words, you read into a function. This is used by e.g. `std::endl` or `std::flush` as well. Using that, you only need a single function for each of the above two classes. The body of those functions is the same as the `operator>>` for the two classes.

Comment: I like this idea. I will try an experiment with this.

Answer (score 4):

`IgnoreUntilNewLine` is too long in my opinion.  I'd simplify it to `ignore_line`.

It probably makes sense to provide the manipulator object in the library instead of letting the user declare one:

```
struct ignore_line_t {
    constexpr explicit ignore_until_newline_t() = default;
    // ...
};
inline constexpr ignore_line_t ignore_line{};
```

so the user can use it directly in a `>>` chain:

```
stream >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> TU::ignore_line
```

Incidentally, we can go further and provide a similar helper for `getline` to fit in the chain:

```
class getline {
    std::string& dest;
public:
    explicit getline(std::string& s)
        : dest{s}
    {
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, getline man)
    {
        return std::getline(is, man.dest);
    }
};
```

so your example can be written simply as

```
stream >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> TU::ignore_line >> TU::getline(tmp.line)
```